# Cart item title isn't concatenated into an HTML table in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have create a Short-Code to list all the item name as follow,

```
add_shortcode( 'show_cart_items', 'tcf_show_cart_items' );
function tcf_show_cart_items()
{
    $cart   =   '<table>';
                foreach(  WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
                {
                    $cart .= '<tr>' . $cart_item['data']->get_title() . '</tr>';
                }
    $cart   .=  '</table>';

    return $cart;
}
```

this is working fine but what I am facing is the items printing out of the table. You can see the output as screenshot when I inspecting on the web page and item name which was not printing in side the HTML table is highlighted in yellow.

[image]

My questions are,

1. What is the reason for this?
2. How to fix this?

TIA.

Comment: This sounds like the `get_title` method was actually outputting the title (echo, print), instead of returning it ... but according to docs, it should do the latter (at least in WC 3, which version are you using?)

Comment: I am using the WC 3, the latest.

Answer (score 1):

try below code, may be concatenate skip code

```
add_shortcode( 'show_cart_items', 'tcf_show_cart_items' );
function tcf_show_cart_items()
{
    $cart_item = '';

    foreach(  WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
    {
        $cart_item .= '<tr>' . $cart_item['data']->get_title() . '</tr>';
    }

    $cart   =   '<table>'.$cart_item.'</table>';

    return $cart;
}
```

Comment: It gives the same output with no luck

Answer (score 1):

You have just forget to add **`<td>`** html tag around the title this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_cart_items', 'tcf_show_cart_items' );
function tcf_show_cart_items()
{
    $cart   =   '<table>';
                foreach(  WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
                    $cart .= '<tr><td>' . $cart_item['data']->get_title() . '</td></tr>';
    $cart   .=  '</table>';

    return $cart;
}
```

Or also this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_cart_items', 'tcf_show_cart_items' );
function tcf_show_cart_items()
{
    $cart   =   '<table><tr>';
                foreach(  WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
                    $cart .= '<td>' . $cart_item['data']->get_title() . '</td>';
    $cart   .=  '</tr></table>';

    return $cart;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works now.